# Trying to implement full view in windows 10 mobile through code but it gives Unhandled exception while deploying on desktop view in windows 10

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to implement full view in Windows 10 mobile view through code. It's working fine in mobile, but when deploying the same code for desktop view I get the following error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFCB9BFD1C4 (twinapi.appcore.dll) in
>   L_c_uwp.exe: 0xC000027B: An application-internal exception has
>   occurred (parameters: 0x000000C517DFECF0, 0x0000000000000001)

How to resolve this? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <MediaElement x:Name="myMediaElement"
        Source="/Video/splash_3.mp4" AutoPlay="True"
        CurrentStateChanged="MediaElement_CurrentStateChanged"/>
</Grid>
```

C# code

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    RemoveGap();
}

private void MediaElement_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (myMediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Paused)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Home));
    }
}

public async void RemoveGap()
{
    await StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().HideAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 Desktops does not have Status Bar so calling `await StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().HideAsync();` causes error.

Instead, we need use the [**ApiInformation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.metadata.apiinformation.aspx) class to check for the presence of [StatusBar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn633864) as this class only exists in Mobile Device (See **Requirements** →  **Device family**).

```
if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar"))
     await StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().HideAsync();
```

For more info, please see [Dynamically detecting features with API contracts](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/09/15/dynamically-detecting-features-with-api-contracts-10-by-10/)

Comment: Actually i am deploying the same code for both desktop and mobile view.How to overcome this issue in code format.

Comment: if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar"))

Comment: and do that HideAsync there

Comment: Exactly what code should be use please provide that i'm not getting anything about this issue.

Comment: Actually i have no idea about how to restrict method "StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().HideAsync();" for Desktop.Any idea of code actually i'm new to app development.

Comment: @anuj I have update answer. Replace the code in the RemoveGap() method with the 2 line code given above